# Soft delete using nodejs + mongodb

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

How do i perform a soft delete using nodejs on mongodb

for example using this code, can it be modified to do a soft delete instead or is there another way?

**Controllers/ category.js**

```
exports.remove = (req, res) => {
    const category = req.category;
    category.remove((error, data) => {
        if (error) {
            return res.status(400).json({
                error: errorHandler(error)
            });
        }
        res.json({
            message: "Category deleted"
        });
    });
};
```

**routes/category.js**

```
const express = require("express");
const router = express.Router();

const { create, categoryById, read, update, remove, list } = require("../controllers/category");
const { requireSignin, isAuth, isAdmin } = require("../controllers/auth");
const { userById } = require("../controllers/user");

router.get("/category/:categoryId", read);
router.post("/category/create/:userId", requireSignin, isAuth, isAdmin, create);
router.put("/category/:categoryId/:userId", requireSignin, isAuth, isAdmin, update);
router.delete("/category/:categoryId/:userId", requireSignin, isAuth, isAdmin, remove);
router.post("/categories", list);

router.param("categoryId", categoryById);
router.param("userId", userById);

module.exports = router;
```

**models/category.js**

```
const mongoose = require("mongoose");

const categorySchema = new mongoose.Schema(
    {
        name: {
            type: String,
            trim: true,
            required: true,
            maxlength: 32
        }
    },
    { timestamps: true }
);

module.exports = mongoose.model("Category", categorySchema);
```

Comment: Please tell what is schema of category?

Comment: What does a "soft delete" **mean to you?** ( Don't presume this is a universal term ). Please explain what you are expecting with specific examples. Show a small sample of documents, an operation and what you expect to happen to the data as a result of that operation. Your current question really does not explain much with the code provided. We can *presume* that `req.category` has been filled with the current mongoose model, or possibly a pre-prepared query. But given no code that shows any interaction with either `:categoryId` or `:userId` from the route, it's just **not very clear*.

Comment: Soft delete as in the data is not deleted from the db. The data is still there but for the user it shows that the "item" or category is deleted.

Comment: @Omar `req.category` is not obvious parameter. is it mongoose model? or is it model instance (result of querying db)?

Comment: i added the models/category.js code

Comment: @Omar, have You checked my answer below?

Comment: I just tried your code and it worked. It printed out "Category deleted" and i checked the db and it was still there. Just want to get one thing straight.  Will it be deleted for the user on the front-end? To clarify, if i delete it will it be removed from the front-end as in, it won't be visible to him (implying it is deleted). Also thanks so much for your help

Comment: @Omar You want soft delete and want to know why it's not deleted? When You check database You should check `deleted` field of that record. Soft delete means data not deleted but marked by some field that it should be hidden (deleted flag). So that's why in my answer I've added read, list methods that do use that field

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure `req.category` is instance of model or model itself.

So in my answer below I assume that somehow You've got instance of model and injected it as `req.category`

1) Add deleted field to schemas where You want to have soft delete:

```
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
const {Schema} = mongoose;

const categorySchema = new Schema(
    {
        name: {
          type: Schema.Types.String,
          trim: true,
          required: true,
          maxlength: 32
        },

        // deleted flag for soft delete feature
        deleted: {
          type: Schema.Types.Boolean,
          index: true,
          default: false
        }
    },
    { timestamps: true }
);

module.exports = mongoose.model("Category", categorySchema);
```

2) Change delete procedure:

```
module.exports.remove = async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const category = req.category; // if it's an instance of model
    // or if it's mongoose model comment line above
    // const category = await req.category.findOne({
    //                                     _id: req.params.categoryId,
    //                                     deleted: false
    //                                   });

    if (!category || category.deleted === true) {
      return res.status(404).json({
        error: 'Requested category does not exist'
      });
    }

    category.deleted = true;
    await category.save();

    res.status(200).json({
      message: "Category deleted"
    });
  }
  catch (error) {
    res.status(400).json({
      error: errorHandler(error)
    });
  }
};
```

3) Change category read route: `/category/:categoryId` handler:

```
module.exports.read = async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const category = req.category; // if it's an instance of model
    // or if it's mongoose model comment line above
    // const category = await req.category.findOne({
    //                                     _id: req.params.categoryId,
    //                                     deleted: false
    //                                   });

    if (!category || category.deleted === true) {
      return res.status(404).json({
        error: 'Requested category does not exist'
      });
    }
    res.status(200).json(category);
  }
  catch (error) {
    res.status(400).json({
      error: errorHandler(error)
    });
  }
};
```

4) Change listing procedure:

```
module.exports.list = async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const categories = await req.category.find({deleted: false});
    res.status(200).json({categories});
  }
  catch (error) {
    res.status(400).json({
      error: errorHandler(error)
    });
  }
};
```

Comment: Listing procedure didn't work. Returned an error, but when i ran my listing code it worked any ideas why?

Comment: @Omar fixed listing code I forgot to put await before req.category.find

Comment: @Omar keep in mind to change Schema according above code

Answer (score 0):

**Step 1:**
Add a new field in your Schema "Deleted" with type Boolean and Default value 'false'

```
deleted: { type: Boolean, default: false }
```

**Step 2**

```
Change Delete Process To:
router.delete('/:id', verifyTokenAndAuthorization, async (req, res) => {
  try {
    await User.findByIdAndUpdate(req.params.id, { deleted: true }); <= change delete status to 'true'
    res.status(200).json('user Deleted');
  } catch (error) {
    res.status(500).json(error)
  }
})
```